# How to disable html img tag rendering from a string while parsing data from rss news

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css

Greetings of the day!

I need to parse dynamic data using rss feeds from the rss url given below and disable rendering of images under the description returned from xml:
[timesofindia - rss feeds](http://timesofindia.feedsportal.com/c/33039/f/533917/index.rss)

Technology used: Html, Css, Asp.net using C#.

Following is the sample description returned from rss:

Angelica Valencia of Queens was advised by her doctor not to work overtime shifts because of her high-risk pregnancy.<img width='1' height='1' src='http://timesofindia.feedsportal.com/c/33039/f/533917/s/3f9f3d41/sc/36/mf.gif' border='0'/><br clear='all'/><br/><br/><a href="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/210474526050/u/0/f/533917/c/33039/s/3f9f3d41/sc/36/rc/1/rc.htm" rel="nofollow"><img src="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/210474526050/u/0/f/533917/c/33039/s/3f9f3d41/sc/36/rc/1/rc.img" border="0"/></a><br/><a href="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/210474526050/u/0/f/533917/c/33039/s/3f9f3d41/sc/36/rc/2/rc.htm" rel="nofollow"><img src="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/210474526050/u/0/f/533917/c/33039/s/3f9f3d41/sc/36/rc/2/rc.img" border="0"/></a><br/><a href="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/210474526050/u/0/f/533917/c/33039/s/3f9f3d41/sc/36/rc/3/rc.htm" rel="nofollow"><img src="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/210474526050/u/0/f/533917/c/33039/s/3f9f3d41/sc/36/rc/3/rc.img" border="0"/></a><br/><br/><a href="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/210474526050/u/0/f/533917/c/33039/s/3f9f3d41/sc/36/a2.htm"><img src="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/210474526050/u/0/f/533917/c/33039/s/3f9f3d41/sc/36/a2.img" border="0"/></a><img width="1" height="1" src="http://pi.feedsportal.com/r/210474526050/u/0/f/533917/c/33039/s/3f9f3d41/sc/36/a2t.img" border="0"/>

Here i need to disable the rendering of all the images example "img width='1' height='1' src='http://timesofindia.feedsportal.com/c/33039/f/533917/s/3f9f3d41/sc/36/mf.gif' border='0'" at run time and also ensuring good performance.

Any suggestion or any example would be great.

Thanx in advance

Comment: The image is only rendered if you output that rss in the HTML. If you have it in memory while parsing it it is not rendered/requested.

Comment: Thanx for the reply, Gaby can u pls explain a bit more, wud be great?

Comment: First the link you posted is XML and not JSON. Second you need to show us how you parse this XML.